Installing Ubuntu studio on Rpi 5
Is it possible to install Ubuntu Studio on a rpi 5 8gb version using the normal image provided on Ubuntus' downloaded page? Is that image compatible? Thank you for any responses.

Select an installer that is suitable for your architecture (Raspberry PIs are either armhf or arm64) and install that; eg. a Ubuntu Server image will install, then add the Ubuntu Studio package(s) on top of that.  I suggest you read the Ubuntu Studio docs though; as the raspberry pi doesn't have sufficient resources to run it well and you can expect the issues the Ubuntu Studio site talks about; however if that won't worry you (ie. you won't be doing those tasks) follow the instructions they provide

This question is similar to: Can I run Ubuntu Studio on a Raspberry pi?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Actually not. The Raspberry Pi has an ARM CPU, thus you and installation image suitable for this CPU architecture, typically called arm64.
Ubuntu Studio only provides images for AMD64 CPUs (Intel, AMD), but not arm64, see Download Page for Ubuntu Studio. Thus, at least at the time of writing this, Ubuntu Studio is not installable on a Raspberry Pi or any other computer with an ARM CPU from a image provide from the developers.
